# Laravel: How to namespace a helper library within a bundle?

Tags: namespaces, bundle, laravel

I've learning through building my first bundle, and am really confused about namespaces / aliases..

I'm trying to create a macro (not sure if this is actually a macro, just looks like one?) inside my bundle which I can call from my views like so:

`{{ CMS::text('1','Title') }}`

or

`{{ \CMS::text('1','Title') }}`

But I'm getting the error:

`Class 'Lax\CMS' not found`

The file containing the code which should produce the output is in **/Lax/libraries/cms.php** and starts: 
`namespace Lax\libraries;`

My bundle **Lax/start.php** has:

```
Autoloader::map(array(
   'Lax_Base_Controller' => Bundle::path('lax').'controllers/cms.php',
   'CMS' => Bundle::path('lax').'libraries/cms.php',
));

Autoloader::namespaces(array(
    'Lax\Models' => Bundle::path('lax').'models',
));
```

To the aliases array in **/application/config/application/** I've added

```
'CMS' => 'Lax\\CMS',
```

**bundles.php:**

```
'lax' => array(
        'auto'      => true,
        'handles'   => 'lax'
    ),
```

What am I doing wrong!?

Any advice gratefully recieved!
Tx, Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are autoloading the Lax\Models namespace, and try to access things from the Lax\Libraries namespace, which isn't autoloaded.
You should consider autoloading the Lax namespace "only", which will allow you to load stuff from any folder you might add in the future.

In code, this is all you would have to do, change:

```
Autoloader::namespaces(array(
    'Lax\Models' => Bundle::path('lax').'models',
));
```

To this:

```
Autoloader::namespaces(array(
    'Lax' => Bundle::path('lax'),
));
```

Now, in your view, you can access the CMS class (in the Lax\Libraries namespace) like this:

```
{{ Lax\Libraries\CMS::some_wicked_cool_method(1, 'title') }}
```

If you want to get rid of the Lax\Libraries part, you can add a "use" statement somewhere at the top of your view like this:

```
<?php use Lax\Libraries\CMS; ?>
```

And then somewhere else in the view, use it like this:

```
{{ CMS::some_wicked_cool_method(1, 'title') }}
```

An even better way would be to "prepare" those variables in your controller, and send them to your view as a simple variable.

It could look like this in your controller

```
<?php

use Lax\Libraries\CMS;

class Some_Controller {

    public function get_index()
    {
        $title = CMS::some_wicked_cool_method(1, 'title');

        return View::make('someview', compact('title'))
    }
}
```

Now, your view goes back to using only this:

```
{{ $title }}
```

Sweet, isn't it?

Comment: ah! so simple! thats what i get for late night tutorial copy pastes - thanks for the detailed answer :)